# Resize Image in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to get an image in Actionscript by using the Loader and URL. The image is coming fine and I am able to display it on screen after the event is completed. What I want to do is resize the image on screen. I am unable to do this. How do I proceed?

I tried setting loader.content.width which didn't work. I tried setting loader.content.scaleX which also didn't work. I am a novice at this, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Loader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) inherits from `DisplayObject`, meaning you need to modify `width`, `height`, etc directly:

```
loader.width = 100;
loader.height = 120;
// etc
```

You can modify any of the properties listed here directly via the instance of `Loader`:

[`Loader` - Property Summary.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#propertySummary)

Comment: Just remember to do it *after* image is loaded and loader.width is not zero, or it won't work too.

Comment: remember also that the image its still the original size in memory. Means this is not a good approach for a mobile application or when you loading lots of big images and scale them down.